# iOS centered scrollview does not scroll with autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am able to get a scrollview working with autolayout when the scrollview is not centered.  But when i center the scrollview it does not work.  Below is my test case:
https://github.com/CorradoDev/ScrollView
There are 2 view controllers.  The one labeled working shows scrolling on the 4s emulator.  The other one where there is a centered scrollview does not work.

Can anyone help me with this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code with the updated constraints.  I had a coworker help me.  Below is the constraints that worked
Main view
 -> ScrollView Content View center this within the superview.  Also set the height and width to be the size of the iphone screen.
      -> Content View pinned to the top left right and bottom.  Also set the size of the height and width.  Which is the size of the scrollable area.

You will have to dynamically change the height of the Scrollview content view in code.  Then on the ipad there is no scrolling but on the 4s there is scrolling.  Then on the iphone 6 there is also no scrolling.

Attached is a screenshot.

If someone can find a solution that does not require you to manually change the height of the scrollview container that would be great.  Otherwise this works just fine.

[image: Screenshot]